# Shiny generated HTML page become grey

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to export Shiny page. For the background the page become grey if it does not connected to the server.

The problem is: I want to export the HTML page, but it is still grey. Do you know how to prevent this problem, or which HTML code do I need to remove?

Comment: This happens when the server code has an error.  The error message should be displayed in the R session where you initiated the Shiny session.  However, this shouldn't stop you from viewing the HTML from your browser. (For example, in chrome, right click anywhere on the page, and select "View page source")

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just run your `ui.r` and it will return some code in `html`. For example, if you run the following lines:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
))
```

You will see:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h2>Hello Shiny!</h2>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <form class="well">
            <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
               <label class="control-label" for="obs">Number of observations:</label>
               <input class="js-range-slider" id="obs" data-min="0" data-max="1000" data-from="500" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="10" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-keyboard="true" data-keyboard-step="0.1" data-drag-interval="true" data-data-type="number"/>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
         <div id="distPlot" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100% ; height: 400px"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then you save the html code as `.html` file you should be able to view the page. If you have visualizations, you might need to create them separately and point the directory in your html code.